# Xamarin forms: Emojis and special characters are not showing properly in push notification title and body

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented push notification in my xamarin forms android part using FCM. When sending a new message the push notification starts work. But the special characters and emojis not showing properly in the notification's title and body.

When I send a new message I encode the message like below and send it to the back end:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(message);
```

When receiving the message I need to decode the message like below. But on where I can add the following code?

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(message);
```

FCM `OnMessageReceived()` will work only when the app is in foreground mode. I added the code on there and tested the emojis in foreground mode. But the emojis are not working properly, showing special characters instead of emoji. Also, how can I decode the message when the app is in killed or background state.

Comment: If you can't do the job in app side, you should ask your back end to encode , decode  the special characters and emojis.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT My back end team using java, can you suggest a solution for decode the special characters and emojis in java. They try like below, but that didn't work. `EmojiParser.parseFromUnicode(msgBody, FitzpatrickAction.PARSE);`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to implement it by using java.